# how to set initial fragment in frame using switch widget

Tags: android, switch-statement, fragment

I am using switch to change fragment in android, and its success, but i didnt find on how to set and show initial fragment in frame.

```
public class SwitchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch swCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);

    swCheck = findViewById(R.id.switch_check);

    swCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (isChecked) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new NewsFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new BoardFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: The quickest solution would be to just perform "click" on a Switch, like this `swCheck.performClick()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace fragments I use an helper method like this: (I keep the backstack but only 1 per fragment class)

```
@Override
public void replaceCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment, String newTag) {

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(newTag) == null) {
        //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.flContainer, fragment, newTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

And I call it like

```
    replaceCurrentFragment(new MenuFragment(), "yourTag");
```

You can use this method both in your switch and in your initial, and your code will look like this:

```
public class SwitchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch swCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);

    swCheck = findViewById(R.id.switch_check);

    swCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (isChecked) {
                replaceCurrentFragment(new NewsFragment(), "yourTag");
            } else {
                replaceCurrentFragment(new BoardFragment(), "yourTag2");
            }
        }
    });

    //to set the initial fragment, just use the replace again here in the oncreate:
    replaceCurrentFragment(new NewsFragment(), "yourTag");
  }

@Override
public void replaceCurrentFragment(Fragment fragment, String newTag) {

    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    String backStateName = fragment.getClass().getName();

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    boolean fragmentPopped = manager.popBackStackImmediate(backStateName, 0);

    if (!fragmentPopped && manager.findFragmentByTag(newTag) == null) {
        //fragment not in back stack, create it.
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content, fragment, newTag);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
}
```

**If you don't want to use the method**

```
public class SwitchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch swCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_switch);

    swCheck = findViewById(R.id.switch_check);

    swCheck.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            if (isChecked) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new NewsFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new BoardFragment()).commit();
            }
        }
    });
  transaction.replace(R.id.content, new BoardFragment()).commit();

}
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @Muci you're welcome, glad it helped with your problem :)